# Testing library asserting multiple objects are equal

Tags: java, unit-testing

It's common in libraries designed for unit testing to have different methods like

```
assertEquals
assertTrue
assertFalse
```

etc. (e.g. Mockito for instance).

However, these methods compare (equals method f.e.) only two arguments.
Let's say i have four values, that I want to compare.

```
Integer a = 4; 
Integer b = 4; 
Integer c = 4; 
Integer d = 4;
```

If I want to compare them, I have to write four lines like this:

```
 assertEquals(a, 4);
 assertEquals(b, 4);
 assertEquals(c, 4);
 assertEquals(d, 4);
```

What I am searching for is, a library that could take more arguments and check if all are equal

```
 assertAllEquals(a, b, c, d, 4);
```

I know that might be not implemented, since there was a discussion in unit-testing only asserting one fact at a time (and this could break the concept). Still, is there any testing library that provides that handy feature?

Comment: Using plain java and JUnit you cloud do something like `assertTrue(Stream.of(a, b, c, d).allMatch(integer -> integer == 4));`

Comment: @MichałKrzywański the issue with that is that you get a meaningless error message.

Comment: `Stream.of(a,b,c,d).forEach(e -> assertEquals(4, e))` might be better; although, that still gives you no indication as to _which_ isn't equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I want to compare them, I have to write four lines like this:

If you're comparing separate variables, that really is the best way. By writing separate assertions, you can actually pinpoint which of the element's *isn't* equal to that value.

If there are so many separate variables that separate assertions is actually a problem, that points to a design issue with too many variables.

---

With that said, you can do something like this:

```
Stream.of(a,b,c,d).forEach(e -> assertEquals(4, e));
```

(Note the parameter ordering for `assertEquals`: expected, then actual. So, you should never have a constant for the "actual" parameter).

This at least gives a useful assertion in that it tells you the actual value that wasn't equal to 4; it's not useful in that it doesn't tell you which of the variables (a-d) it is.

You can get a *slightly* more useful error message using something like:

```
List<Integer> actual = List.of(a,b,c,d);
List<Integer> expected = Collections.nCopies(actual.size(), 4);
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

This at least gives you an indication of which element(s) in the `actual` list is different from 4.